# c# google weather xml getting

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-weather-api

i want get weather from `http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=` I use this

```
    // load xml result from Google weather
    var addr = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=lt");
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(addr);


// navigate to current conditions node
var current_conditions = from currentCond in xd.Root.Descendants("current_conditions")
select currentCond;

// navigate to Forecast info node
var forcastInfo = from forecastinfo in xd.Root.Descendants("forecast_information")
select forecastinfo;
```

I use url `http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=lt` but information get in english, I can't find problem please help :)

Comment: When I open the url in my browser, I don't see any English word, but only Lithuanian. How does the result look when you open it in the browser?

Comment: in english ;( maybe problem is in location setting in pc

Comment: I'm in Germany and my browser is German, too, so this should be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455335/loading-xml-to-an-xdocument-with-a-url-containing-an-ampersand) - no need for WebUtility.HtmlEncode as you get "amp;hl=lt" query parameter instead of "hl=lt".

English result: `http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&amp;hl=lt`

Non-English result:`http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=lt`

Comment: see my pirst post I not use `&amp;` but url is still vrong

Comment: Wrong in what sense? server does not seem to return valid XML from what I can tell, but there is nothing wrong with url itself.

Comment: Error `Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 473.`

Comment: @user1069874: See my [updated reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10455358/1149773).